# Swift for-loop wont accept index as a variable multiplied with a size.widht value

Tags: swift, for-loop, indexing

Code:

The issue: Im not allowed to operate the index to size.widht. I know its an CG value but I am allowed to operate with literals. However, when I try to use an declared int instead it doesnt allows it either.

size.widht/5 * (index + 1) says "Cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '($T6,($T10))'.

```
func addBricks(CGsize) {
    for var index = 0; index < 4; index++ {
    var brick = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "brick")
    brick.physicsBody = SKPhysiscsBody(rectangleOfSize: brick.frame.size)

    var xPos = size.widht/5 * (index + 1)
    var yPos = size.height - 50
    brick.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)
    self.addChild(brick)
    }
}
```

What could possible be wrong?

Comment: You can't multiply CGFloat and Int. try CGFloat(index)  + 1